# How to populate KeyValuePair<int, int> inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, logic, keyvaluepair

I have this code snippet as below which iterates over a split string.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.ContactNumber))
        {
            var splitContract = profile.ContactNumber.Split(new string[] { "and", "&" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var contract in splitContract)
            {
                //check the split if it contains "x" or "X" character - if it does contain, it means it's a valid contract
                if (contract.Contains("x") || contract.Contains("X"))
                {
                    var condensedString = contract.Replace(" ", "");
                    var split = condensedString.Split(new char[] { 'x', 'X' });

                    GetNumbersOnly(split);
                }
            }    
        }

private void GetNumbersOnly(string[] inputArray)
    {
        var ListKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach (var item in inputArray)
        {
            var numberToAdd = Regex.Replace(item, "[^0-9]", "", RegexOptions.None);

            ListKeyValuePair.Add(?, ?);
        }
    }
```

In GetNumbersOnly method, how can I populate List of KeyValuePair inside the for each loop?

The inputArray variable has an array element of [0] = 100, [1] = 5 for the first iteration and so on.

This is the desired output for the KeyValuePair {100, 5}, {200, 10}, {500, 15}.

Sorry, I can't seem to find any related scenario when I googled it.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the key and value are stored in separate array items, your logic is dependent on *order*.  In cases like this, you should avoid `for...each` and instead use plain old `for`, which allows you to control the manner of iteration.

```
private void GetNumbersOnly(string[] inputArray)
{
    var ListKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    for (int i=0; i< inputArray.Length; i+=2)  //The "2" here is very important!
    {
        var numberToAdd1 = Regex.Replace(inputArray[i], "[^0-9]", "", RegexOptions.None);
        var numberToAdd2 = Regex.Replace(inputArray[i+1], "[^0-9]", "", RegexOptions.None);

        ListKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(numberToAdd1, numberToAdd2));
    }
}
```

Comment: ListKeyValuePair.Add(numberToAdd1, numberToAdd2); returns an error.  "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"  ListKeyValuePair is a list, I tried AddRange but still the same error.

Comment: Oh, I get it now @John Wu, that line should be like this ListKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(numberToAdd1, numberToAdd2));

Answer (score 0):

The ListKeyValuePair.Add(  ) function is expecting 1 field which is of type KeyValuePair.  You need to make one of these with a new KeyValuePair() { key = item, value = numberToAdd };

Why are you keeping key value pairs in a list?  Why not a Dictionary ?  Do you want duplicate pairs?

Comment: Good suggestion, I don't want to duplicate pairs.  If I'm going to use Dictionary<string, string> how to populate dictionary based on the code?

Comment: Dictionary<string,string> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();   ...  MyDict.Add(item,numberToAdd);     You may want to check if the key already exists  if (MyDict.ContainsKey(item) )  { // warn user } else { // add it}

Comment: what is item in MyDict.Add(item, numberToAdd)? sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: @Juniuz:  item is the key in the key value pair.  I saw that you were looping over item in "foreach (var item in inputArray)" so I assumed that you would want item to be the key.  You can use whichever key makes sense.